# Ayuda en OpenGL funcion glutMouseFun()

Tags: c++, opengl, mouse

quisiera que por favor alguien me ayude o me de una explicacion con respecto a un problema presentado con la funcion **glutMouseFunc()**, he creado una clase que se llama Button

```
class Button{ 
private:
    char *texto;
    int iniX;
    int iniY;
    int tamX;
    int tamY;
    void (*accion)();
public:
    Button(char *, int, int);
    void dibujar();
    void onMouseClick(int, int, int, int);
    void mouseClickLeft(void()); 
};
```

lo que pasa es que al implementar las funciones **mouseClickLeft()** y **onMouseClick()** me aparece un error.

```
void Button::mouseClickLeft(void func())
{
    accion = func;
    glutMouseFunc(onMouseClick);
}

void Button::onMouseClick(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        if((x>iniX && x<(iniX+tamX))&&(y<iniY && y>(iniY-tamY)))
        {
            accion;
        }
    }
}
```

al querer pasar la funcion **onMouseClick** a la funcion **glutMouseFun()**, me dice que hay un error de conversion. Alguien me puede guiar a una posible solucion, ya que quisiera generalizar la funcion y asi al momento de crear una instancia de objetos poder llamar a la funcion **mouseClickLeft()** y haga todo el trabajo.

Comment: Si pusieras la línea exacta en la que tienes el problema (y algo de contexto), junto al código de error, sería mucho mas fácil ayudarte. Así, solo se puede intentar adivinar cual es tu problema. Un saludo :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema según estube viendo es cuando haces esta llamada:

```
glutMouseFunc(onMouseClick);
```

A pesar de que la function **onMouseClick()** la hayas declarado la función con cuatro enteros, al ser un método del objeto, lleba implicitamente otro parámetro que es el puntero **this**.

El problema seria declarar el método **onMouseClick()** como **static**. Pero aparece otro problema es que no puedes acceder a los atributos del objeto Button desde esta función.

Yo lo resolvería de la siguiente manera;

```
class Button;
std::vector<Button*> allButtons;
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Rect
{
public:
    int rx;
    int ry;
    int rw;
    int rh;
public:
    Rect()
    {
    }
    bool contains(int x, int y) const
    {
        if(rx > x && ry > y && (rx+rw) < x && (ry+rh) < y)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Button
{
private:
    Rect rect;
    const char* texto;
    void (*action)();
public:
    Button(int x, int y, const char* texto, void (*action)());
    ~Button();
    const Rect& getRect() const
    {
        return rect;
    }
    void dibujar();
    void onMouseClick(int button, int state, int x, int y);
};

Button::Button(int x, int y, const char* _texto, void (*_action)())
{
    rect.rx = x;
    rect.ry = y;
    rect.rw = 100;
    rect.rh = 50;
    texto = _texto;
    action = _action;
    allButtons.push_back(this);
}
Button::~Button()
{
    std::vector<Button*>::iterator it;
    for(it = allButtons.begin(); it != allButtons.end(); it++)
    {
        if((*it) == this)
            allButtons.erase(it);
        break;
    }
}
void Button::onMouseClick(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    action();
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void onGlutMouseClick(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    std::vector<Button*>::const_iterator it;
    for(it = allButtons.begin(); it != allButtons.end(); it++)
    {
        if((*it)->getRect().contains(x, y))
        {
            (*it)->onMouseClick(button, state, x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Registrar cuando inicias el programa la captura de evento click

```
glutMouseFunc(onGlutMouseClick);
```